# ASP.NET/C# use calender to show available dates and unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

I am currently working on a website that allow people to book basketball court online and will need to use calender to show the available dates and unavailable dates

So let's say for example, if the dates is available, the people can select the dates, however if its unavailable, the dates will appear to be different color and people cannot select that particular dates but can view it.

Can it be done?

Moreover, the calender should also retrieve data from my SQL to generate the available and unavailable dates

What I was thinking initially is to have a SQL Table called "Calender" with attributes of 'Availability' ('Available' or 'Unavailable'), 'StartingDate', and 'EndingDate'.

So for example, from 24/6/2017 (StartingDate) until 26/6/2017 (EndingDate), Unavailable (Availability), by using that row in SQL then I can generate the calender.

Hope you guys understand,

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it can be done. ;-)

Comment: No it can't. Don't send them on a suicide mission.

Comment: @JohnWu Sorry, what do you mean by that? Thanks